# Make a program that checks excel cell if it contains specific formating and formula

Tags: excel

I would love to make so I can make one program. I have excel worksheets, and I have to check if cell contains a formula =A1+B1( as example ), and i have multiple formulas that i eant to check if they are correct. So in case I wrote =A1+B1, but i had to write A3*A4, and if thats the case, it tells that on that task there was mistake.
Would it be possible to make as
1)External prgramm
2) inside excel with macros.
What would be the best way of doing this? I was thinking about Visual Basics, but havent worked with it yet, so maybe there are already premade examples already.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your formula is present in column C,

- Select column C
- Click conditional formatting --> new rule
- Select "use a formula to determine which cells to format"
- enter the below formula in the formula box
- Select a formatting color and press ok

Formula:

```
=FORMULATEXT(C1)="=A1+B1"
```

You could repeat the same for what all columns you need, but only thing has to be changed is "C1". If you want to do the same for column "F", replace C1 with F1.

Now you have highlighted whichever cells has this formula "=A1+B1". If required you can replace them. You can also do the same for some other formula with some other formatting color. Hope this helps.

Comment: And how would i be able to check the formating? Cell width, background color ect